# Why am I getting a corrupted ViewState error when I try and encasulate a 2D array inside a property to persist it between postbacks?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-4.0, webforms

Basically I am trying to use the ViewState to persist objects between postbacks. Furthermore, I am trying to encapsulate these objects inside a property in a private class.

The purpose of this is to re factor existing code which was previously using static fields to persist the objects, and this was obviously causing problems.

So here is a really simplistic example of the HTML for the webform:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication3.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is a really simplistic example of the initial code-behind (not written by myself):

```
using System;
using System.Web.UI;

namespace WebApplication3
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : Page
    {
        private static string[,] _my2DArray;

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                _my2DArray = new string[3,3];

                for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
                {
                    for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++)
                    {
                        _my2DArray[i, j] = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                    }
                }
            }

            TextBox1.Text = _my2DArray[1, 1];
        }
    }
}
```

This achieves the goal of persisting the object between postbacks, but causes problems as it persists the object between everything else as well.

My idea was to refactor it into something like this, as there is **a lot** of code-behind which uses this object, and there is many more objects in the actual application. I want to fix the problem while changing as little code as possible (resharper makes it easy to move fields out into a seperate class, and turn them into properties. I then amended the property code to work with the Viewstate as opposed to a private backing field):

```
using System;
using System.Web.UI;

namespace WebApplication3
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : Page
    {
        internal class MyClass
        {
            private readonly WebForm1 _webForm1;

            internal MyClass(WebForm1 webForm1)
            {
                _webForm1 = webForm1;
            }

            internal string[,] My2DArray
            {
                set { _webForm1.ViewState["_my2DArray"] = value; }
                get { return (string[,])_webForm1.ViewState["_my2DArray"]; }
            }
        }

        private MyClass _myClass;

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _myClass = new MyClass(this);

            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                _myClass.My2DArray = new string[3,3];

                for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
                {
                    for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++)
                    {
                        _myClass.My2DArray[i, j] = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                    }
                }
            }

            TextBox1.Text = _myClass.My2DArray[1, 1];
        }
    }
}
```

This nearly worked. As well as the 2D array there are strings ints and booleans which all work as expected using this method. But when I bring a 2d array into the mix, I get the below error:

> The state information is invalid for this page and might be corrupted.

Source error:

> [No relevant source lines]

Stack Trace:

```
[EndOfStreamException: Unable to read beyond the end of the stream.]
   System.IO.BinaryReader.ReadByte() +9616466
   System.Web.UI.ObjectStateFormatter.DeserializeValue(SerializerBinaryReader reader) +44
   System.Web.UI.ObjectStateFormatter.DeserializeValue(SerializerBinaryReader reader) +380
   System.Web.UI.ObjectStateFormatter.Deserialize(Stream inputStream) +141

[ArgumentException: The serialized data is invalid.]
   System.Web.UI.ObjectStateFormatter.Deserialize(Stream inputStream) +205
   System.Web.UI.ObjectStateFormatter.Deserialize(String inputString) +337
   System.Web.UI.ObjectStateFormatter.System.Web.UI.IStateFormatter.Deserialize(String serializedState) +4
   System.Web.UI.Util.DeserializeWithAssert(IStateFormatter formatter, String serializedState) +37
   System.Web.UI.HiddenFieldPageStatePersister.Load() +147

[ViewStateException: Invalid viewstate. 
    Client IP: 127.0.0.1
    Port: 
    Referer: http://localhost:27314/WebForm1.aspx
    Path: /WebForm1.aspx
    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/29.0.1547.62 Safari/537.36
    ViewState: /wEPDwULLTE0MDM4MzYxMjMPFgIeBkZvb2JhcmRkem7xFcvXyGXVXNDDKHSutQ9j/EhfbWTpihkzXIlH66A=]

[HttpException (0x80004005): The state information is invalid for this page and might be corrupted.]
   System.Web.UI.ViewStateException.ThrowError(Exception inner, String persistedState, String errorPageMessage, Boolean macValidationError) +198
   System.Web.UI.ViewStateException.ThrowViewStateError(Exception inner, String persistedState) +14
   System.Web.UI.HiddenFieldPageStatePersister.Load() +251
   System.Web.UI.Page.LoadPageStateFromPersistenceMedium() +106
   System.Web.UI.Page.LoadAllState() +43
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +8431
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +253
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest() +78
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestWithNoAssert(HttpContext context) +21
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) +49
   ASP.webform1_aspx.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) in c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\37286ff3\6dc3cf92\App_Web_t5caigbu.0.cs:0
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +100
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +75
```

I am stumped. If you create a new Webforms solution in VS and copy the HTML + code behind above into their respective files you will have exactly what I have.

I am using Visual Studio 2010 and targeting .Net 4.

Any ideas as to why I get this error when I use this method to persist objects between postbacks with 2D arrays, but with no other type of object?

Cheers

Comment: I read in a couple of different places that the ViewState was the correct way to persist objects between postbacks. Is this not the case? I'm fairly new to WebForms.

Comment: Specifically for the [state of controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx) themselves... I could understand if you were creating a custom control, but even then most of the controls that make up your composite would be able to handle their own ViewState persistence. Have you considered the [Session](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581(VS.100).aspx), or [Cache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xsbfdd8c(v=vs.90).aspx)?

Comment: Ah, I just tried using the Session and I don't get this problem. I guess that's an answer then?

Comment: As far as I remember two dimensional arrays are not XmlSerializable. I guess that's why your code fails. Provided it's true, I don't see any issue other than changing this 2-dimensional type used in "a lot of code-behind" :-(

Comment: @jbl True, though one might be inclined to say the same should happen for adding it to the Session in that case - this is not so: the Session contents is stored in memory by default (with a mode of `InProc`) and doesn't undergo serialization - only when the Session backing store is an external source will variables be serialized, hence no issue by default. JMK, sorry, got busy for the time being, I'll check back to see if you've formulated a self-answer by then and if not I'll try to sum it up.

Comment: Come to think of it, @JMK, when you say "causes problems as it persists the object between everything else as well", I take it the variables should not be shared between users? If they _should_ be reused, then use the Cache instead.

Comment: @GrantThomas Thanks very much, I appreciate it. I don't want these variables to be shared between users, so using the Session seems to do the trick, cheers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I remember multi dimensional arrays are not XmlSerializable, which is the serialization mode used by the ViewState.

As to sessions, as long as you use InProc mode, objects will be stored in memory and you won't encounter this issue. The problem will be the same if you try to use a session mechanism requiring xml serialization, like a database storage.

If possible:

- change the type of your two dimensional array : for example to an array of arrays (`String[][]`) in your many pages...
- if you have a common hierarchy for your pages, maybe you can try to override `SaveViewState` and `LoadViewState` to perform custom serialization of your array.

not tried, but my first attempt to override would look like this

```
protected override void LoadViewState(object savedState)
{
    base.LoadViewState(savedState);

    string[,] my2DArray = myMethodForDeserializing2DArrayFromCustomFormat(ViewState["my2DArray"]);
    ViewState["my2DArray"] = my2DArray;
}

protected override object SaveViewState()
{
    string my2DArraySerialized = myMethodForSerializing2DArrayToCustomFormat(ViewState["my2DArray"]);
    ViewState["my2DArray"] = my2DArraySerialized;
    return base.SaveViewState();
}
```